# How to define variables $a$,$b$,$c$,$d$ are all elements of set $\{2,3,5,7\}$?

Tags: variable-definitions, constraint, sets

I would appreciate it if somebody could help me with the following problem:

I want to create a Wolfram Language expression  that states that all $a$,$b$,$c$,$d$ variables are elements of the set $\{2,3,5,7\}$

My attempt is this

```
2 <= {a, b, c} <= 7 && a != 4 && b != 4 && c != 4 && a != 6 && b != 6 && c != 6
```

It can be defined as above, but I think there is another simpler way.

**What would be a good way of writing this expresion?**

Comment: What about `Element[{a,b,c,d},{2,3,5,7}]`?

Comment: and what about `MemberQ[set, x]` if you wan to check that `x` is element of the set.

Comment: `AllTrue[{a,b,c,d},AnyTrue[{2,3,5,7},EqualTo@#]&]`

Comment: It really depends on intended usage. For pattern matching `Alternatives` can be used. For mathematical programming maybe a logical expression. If they all need to take on distinct values, that would necessitate yet another representation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
And @@ Or @@@ (Thread[# == {2, 3, 5, 7}] & /@ {a, b, c, d})
```

> `(a == 2 || a == 3 || a == 5 || a == 7) && (b == 2 || b == 3 ||  b == 5 || b == 7) && (c == 2 || c == 3 || c == 5 ||  c == 7) && (d == 2 || d == 3 || d == 5 || d == 7)`

Comment: thank you I will use it well.

Answer (score 2):

Or another [`Alternatives`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives.html)

```
And@@Thread[{a, b, c, d}==Alternatives@@{2, 3, 5, 7}]
```

> ```
> a == (2 | 3 | 5 | 7) && b == (2 | 3 | 5 | 7) && c == (2 | 3 | 5 | 7) && d == (2 | 3 | 5 | 7)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

One idea is to use [`Element`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Element) with the [`Region`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Region) primitive [`Point`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Point). Let `v` be your variables, and `r` be your values.

```
v = {a, b, c, d};
r = {2, 3, 5, 7};
```

Then, the following expression asserts your desired condition:

```
cond = Alternatives @@ List /@ v ∈ Point[List /@ r]
```

> ({a} | {b} | {c} | {d}) ∈ Point[{{2}, {3}, {5}, {7}}]

For example:

```
Minimize[a + b + c - d, cond]
```

> {-1, {a -> 2, b -> 2, c -> 2, d -> 7}}

Another idea is:

```
reg = RegionProduct @@ ConstantArray[Point[List /@ r], 4];
```

so that:

```
Minimize[a+b+c-d, {a, b, c, d} ∈ reg]
```

> {-1, {a -> 2, b -> 2, c -> 2, d -> 7}}